# How does Mobizen for Samsung record Samsung Android devices' screen?

Tags: java, android

Came across an Android App called Mobizen for Samsung. It can record screen for android 4.2 and above without root, without USB, without adb. It just works.

It seams to just work for Samsung phone. I didn't test on other brands.

Any of you guy knows how do they do that programmatically? What APIs are they using? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The same question above. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It appears they have a special relationship with Samsung, which probably allows the app hooks into the OS. There is another version for Mobizen called Mobizen for Android that is for everything else but Samsung devices.